# Get the value using a key vs conditional statements

Tags: javascript, performance, typescript, ecmascript-6, conditional-statements

I am trying to optimize the performance of a slider which has many conditional statements that execute on sliding / swiping.

Which way has better performance?

**1- Accessing a prepared object with the key condition**

```
const controller = (config) => {
    top: {
      positionVertical: false,
      orderAfter: false,
      width: '100%',
      height: config.height + 'px',
    },
    bottom: {
      positionVertical: false,
      orderAfter: true,
      width: '100%',
      height: config.height + 'px',
    },
    left: {
      positionVertical: true,
      orderAfter: false,
      width: config.width + 'px',
      height: '100%'
    },
    right: {
      positionVertical: true,
      orderAfter: true,
      width: config.width + 'px',
      height: '100%'
    }
};

this.gallery.sub$.pipe(
  map(({state, config}) => this.controller(config)[config.position])
);
```

**2- Using a standard if-else or switch case statements**

```
this.gallery.sub$.pipe(
  map(({state, config}) => {
    switch(config.position) {
       case 'top': return {
         positionVertical: false,
         orderAfter: false,
         width: '100%',
         height: config.height + 'px',
       }
       case 'left': return {
         positionVertical: true,
         orderAfter: false,
         width: config.width + 'px',
         height: '100%'
       }
       case 'right': return {
         positionVertical: true,
         orderAfter: true,
         width: config.width + 'px',
         height: '100%'
       }
       default: return {
         positionVertical: false,
         orderAfter: true,
         width: '100%',
         height: config.height + 'px',
      }
    }
  })
);
```

Extra explanation is appreciated

Comment: _Which way has better performance?_ - execute both scenarios and check execution time - which faster - use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very likely that you'll never see any performance difference between the two versions of the code. According to Yuan's test results, there shouldn't be any noticeable difference even with 10,000 entries in your slider. I assume those tests were on a desktop CPU, but even on a mobile CPU it shouldn't make much difference.

That said, it is easy to tell from first principles which version is likely to be faster: the second one, simply because it does a lot less work. Yuan's tests bear this out for an extreme case of 10,000,000 entries (although I haven't looked at the detailed test setup).

Why is the second one faster? Look at the first one. For each entry, it does the following:

1. Calculates all the values for all four cases and creates an object for each.
2. Constructs a new outer object containing all four of those inner objects.
3. Selects one of those inner objects according to `config.position` and discards the rest.

The second version simply does this:

1. Uses `config.position` to select which of the four types of objects to create.
2. Constructs only that one object and not the other three.
3. There is no step 3.

It stands to reason that calculating and constructing four different objects, plus a wrapper object to hold them all, will take longer than only calculating and constructing *one* of those objects.

Stylistically, there is one thing I would change in the second version. The `default:` case should be `case 'bottom':` to match the rest and make the intent more clear.

Answer (score 1):

So easy,I do a test

[Here is two kind different functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LnAl.jpg)

[Test controller,we loop 10000000 times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEak2.jpg)

[Test controller1,same loop times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZI6HB.jpg)

[first function is 288ms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhJaE.jpg)

[second function is 159ms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9TeS.jpg)

Comment: Look at it another way: Does OP's slider have 10,000,000 entries in it? Probably not. Maybe 1000? That seems more likely. So divide each of your results by 10,000. First function is now .028ms for 1000 entries, while second function is .016ms. That is a whopping .012ms faster. Now, is it important to run this code .012ms faster? Then you might care about the performance of the two versions. Otherwise, the performance difference doesn't matter and other factors should inform which version to use.

Comment: if we don't make more than 1000000,we don't know which is faster,It's just answer the question.In fact,we of course haven't more than 10000000 entries in a page.

Comment: That's my point: it's pretty unlikely that the performance difference matters in any real use of the code. Even with 10,000 entries the difference is only a tenth of a millisecond. Your test is still useful, of course, even if it just demonstrates that there wouldn't be much of a difference in practice.

Comment: Thanks for the exchange